# Signing PDF - memory consumption

Tags: itext, itextpdf

I tried some utilities for digital PDF signing based on iText v1 or v2 and found out that it seems whole PDF is loaded into memory (for 60M PDF process can take up to 300-400MB of memory).

Can recent iText versions sign PDF without load it into memory?

### Updates

I tested Bruno's example with itextpdf 5.5.6

- PdfReader constructor doesn't matter - it can be (src) or (src, null, true), or
  (src, null, false) - result the same.
- what matters is new File(tmp) in createSignature.

But memory consumption is still to big. I tried to sign 100M file (it's PDF with embedded attachment), peak memory is about 325M. Sure, it's better than 540M without temporary file, but not good enough (((.

With 32K file max. memory was 65M (that's JVM and java code itself, I guess)

Memory was measured with `/usr/bin/time -v java ....`

I limited Java memory with `-Xmx100m`, but it crashed with out of memory:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>
> at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.getStreamBytesRaw(PdfReader.java:2576)
>       at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.getStreamBytesRaw(PdfReader.java:2615)
>       at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRStream.toPdf(PRStream.java:230)
>       at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfIndirectObject.writeTo(PdfIndirectObject.java:158)
>       at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.write(PdfWriter.java:420)
>       at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:398)
>       at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addToBody(PdfWriter.java:887)
>       at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.close(PdfStamperImp.java:412)
>       at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.close(PdfStamperImp.java:386)
>       at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.preClose(PdfSignatureAppearance.java:1316)
>       at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.signDetached(MakeSignature.java:140)

Code is:

```
public static byte[] getStreamBytesRaw(final PRStream stream, final RandomAccessFileOrArray file) throws IOException {
        PdfReader reader = stream.getReader();
        byte b[];
        if (stream.getOffset() < 0)
            b = stream.getBytes();
        else {
      ----> b = new byte[stream.getLength()];
            file.readFully(b);
```

I see in debugger that stream type is EmbeddedFile and length is 100M - so whole embedded file is being read into memory.

### Update - create big PDF

It's difficult to share 100M file )), but here is create sequence:

1. Run `dd if=/dev/urandom of=file.bin bs=1048000 count=100`
2. Go to http://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/pdf-tools/ and take http://didierstevens.com/files/software/make-pdf_V0_1_6.zip
3. Unzip and run `python make-pdf-embedded.py file.bin file.pdf`

Here you are )

I should note that it's important to use **/dev/urandom**. **/dev/zero** creates compressed PDF with only 100K size.

Anyway, if it's necessary to obtain my file I've created 50M file on server - http://50mpdf.tk/50m.pdf

Comment: Do you have the option to generate the PDF page by page? Then you write the latest page to file, and then continue processing. Once the page is done, you append it to the existing file (assuming it doesn't have to load the entire document to do so)

Comment: No, I need to sign whole PDF.

Comment: @Voval Your updates look like the memory depletion occurs when iText reorganizes the objects of the stamped PDF. Thus, you may want to apply the signature in append mode. That way iText does not need to read big streams into memory. Use `PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', new File(tmp), true)`

Comment: Tried, no effect. It reads whole embedded file to memory and crashes in the same place.

Comment: More exactly it tries to allocate buffer for whole attachment.

Comment: Can you share your PDF to reproduce the issue? It seems to be connected with your big attachment, but maybe there are additional peculiarities.

Comment: See question update.

Comment: Using @Bruno's code with your 50m.pdf and `-Xmx50m` I also get that `OutOfMemoryError`. Switching to append mode, i.e. using `PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', new File(tmp), true)`, the sample runs properly even with `-Xmx7m`. This should disprove your *Tried, no effect*... (The JRE you use may make a difference, too; I'm using Java 8; there are fundamental differences between Java 7 and Java 8 concerning the memory management.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While signing a PDF, iText uses relevant amounts of memory

- reading the whole unsigned PDF into memory unless using a `PdfReader` in *partial mode*;
- creating the signed file in memory unless using a `PdfStamper` configured to use a temporary file; and
- reading whole individual PDF objects (e.g. streams containing embedded files) into memory when copying the unsigned data to the to-be-signed file unless using a `PdfStamper` in *append mode*.

E.g. signing the sample 50 MB file supplied by the OP requires

- about `-Xmx240m` if using neither append mode, nor a temporary file, nor partial mode;
- about `-Xmx81m` if using a temporary file but not append mode, partial mode makes no difference;
- about `-Xmx7m` if using append mode and a temporary file, partial mode makes no difference.

The reason why partial mode makes no difference in the later cases, is that even in non-partial-mode the `PdfReader` does not seems to read stream *contents* during initialization. As the sample file consists mostly of the contents of a single big stream, the few objects read or not read during initialization don't make a difference, especially as even in partial mode the `PdfReader` reads and keeps some objects in memory which reflect the global document structure, e.g. the page tree.

You can find my test routines here: [CreateSignature.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/signature/CreateSignature.java). I ran it on a 64bit MS Windows Java 8 using iText 5.5.7-SNAPSHOT (which should not differ from the 5.5.6 release in this context).

Thus, for memory-friendly signing use this variant of @Bruno's code:

```
// Creating the reader and the stamper
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filepath, null, true);
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
PdfStamper stamper =
    PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', new File(tmp), true);
// Creating the appearance
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
appearance.setReason(reason);
appearance.setLocation(location);
appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");
// Creating the signature
ExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, pks, chain,
    null, null, null, 0, subfilter);
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Finally it works in Java 7/Linux. Unfortunately I even can't vote up for you and Bruno )

Comment: *can't vote up* - you need only 15 rep for that... if you accept answers (click the tick mark on the left of the respectively best answer to each of your questions), you'll easily get there. ;)

Comment: I'd like to add that total memory consumption by java can much more than -Xmx limit and depends on total memory available, etc. But it's has nothing to do with iText )

Comment: Right, xmx is only one part of the story, and it furthermore differs between java versions which parts there are.

Answer (score 2):

Please download the free ebook [Digital Signatures for PDF documents](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-digital-signatures-for-pdf.html). Section 2.2.4 is entitled "Signing large PDF files". It explains how to sign a document using a temporary file instead of keeping the file in memory:

```
// Creating the reader and the stamper
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filepath, null, true);
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
PdfStamper stamper =
    PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', new File(tmp));
// Creating the appearance
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
appearance.setReason(reason);
appearance.setLocation(location);
appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");
// Creating the signature
ExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, pks, chain,
    null, null, null, 0, subfilter);
```

Do you see how we create the `PdfStamper` instance? We add a `File` object as an extra parameter to the `createSignature()` method. The `tmp` variable in this code sample can be a path to a specific file or to a directory. In case a directory is chosen, iText will create a file with a unique name in that directory.

If you use the `createSignature()` method with a temporary file, you can use an `OutputStream` (the `os` value) that is `null`. In that case, the temporary file will serve as the actual destination file. This is good practice if your goal is to store a signed file on your file system. If the `OutputStream` is not `null`, iText will always try to delete the temporary file after the signing is done.

Please do not use iText v1 or v2 anymore. The types of signatures created with those versions are outdated, and so are the iText versions (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially).

Comment: Thanks, Bruno, I'll take a look!<br/>

>>>Please do not use iText v1 or v2 anymore.<br/>
It's not that I use it ))), I just found several free utilities using iText.

Comment: `PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);` - This constructor parses the complete PDF into memory. You might want to use a different constructor using partial mode.

Comment: What is OP and how to use append mode? Thanks.

Comment: *What is OP* - see http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/O/op_original_poster.html --- *how to use append mode* - see my comment to your question.